# Python BeautifulSoup AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python, html, beautiful-soup

*Я только учусь делать парсер на практике. Делаю также как, человек из видео (на YouTube).
Но почему-то* выдаёт ошибку: **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'**

Я понимаю, что такого атрибута нету. Человек делал также, но у него получалось.
Я как-будто 1 только titles могу передать. Хотя я пробовал, использовать только links или usd_prices.
Всё без толка. Ничего не работает. Смотрел, что можно другим способом. Например requests_html. Я немного попробовал, ничего не получилось.

Даже если сработает сработает другой способ, то почему другому человеку из видео, это получилось?
Я видел, код поменялся HTML. Но я не остановился. Я стал дальше пробовать! Всё конечно без толка. Ой. Чуть-чуть я сменил тему.

Код:

```
def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('section', class_='proposition')

    cars = []
    for item in items:
        titles = item.find('div', class_='proposition_title').get_text(strip=True)
        links = item.find('section', class_='proposition').find('a').get('href')
        # usd_prices = item.find('span', class_='green bold size22 tooltip-price')

        cars.append(
            {
                'title': titles,
                'link': links,
                # 'usd_price': usd_prices,
            }
        )

        print(cars)
```

[image: Полная ошибка]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ниже - способ обхода ошибки. Для того чтобы найти решение и причину нужны исходники

```py
# Не стройте никогда таких цепочек без проверки каждого элемента
# item.find('section', class_='proposition').find('a').get('href')
# Если конечно не сами страницу создавали и то  не стоит

link = None
if section_tag := item.find('section', class_='proposition'):
    if link_tag := section_tag.find('a'):
        link = link_tag.get('href')
```

Можно это компактней записать, но так наглядней

Comment: Может это и показаться глупым. Но, что это: section_fag. У меня из за него ещё ошибка выходит.

Comment: @Snowman222, Нет не глупо, я когда писал ошибся в имени переменной теперь поправил